# Storing dates to skip in python config file

Tags: python, datetime, config

In my config I have

```
SKIP_DATES = ['2016-02-11', '2016-02-13']
```

Then in my script I have

```
if dt.date() in config.SKIP_DATES:
    print "Skipping date: {0}".format(dt.date())
    continue
```

But this will not work because dt.date is a datetime.date object and config.SKIP_DATES is a list of 'string dates'.

How can I easily get around this?

Can anyone suggest a better name for this post?

Comment: Can you please give output of print dt.date()?

Comment: dt.date():  2016-02-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates seem to be in the same format as [`date.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat):

```
date.isoformat()
Return a string representing the date in ISO 8601 format, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’. 
For example, date(2002, 12, 4).isoformat() == '2002-12-04'.
```

So you could do:

```
if dt.date().isoformat() in config.SKIP_DATES:
    print "Skipping date: {0}".format(dt.date())
    continue
```

Note that the string representation of `datetime.date` uses the same function:

```
date.__str__()
For a date d, str(d) is equivalent to d.isoformat().
```

This is why `print dt.date()` gives output like `'2016-10-31'`. Of course, you could then use a set instead of a list for storing your skip dates.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `dt` datetime object to string:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime(2016, 2, 11)
print(date_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) % prints string: 2016-02-11
```

And then check if its in the date string array. Or do it oposite.